# Grep for groups with more than one user

Tags: debian, grep, group

We are getting ready to migrate to Active Directory-based Samba, from the old style domain. Currently all our groups are flat - users belong to groups, but groups can't belong to other groups. Since I want to change that, I need to list all the groups with users.

The catch is that there are thousands of users, and thousands of groups. What I need is to list the groups with 2 or more members, then only show the group name on the command line. This should eliminate user-groups, or groups with only one user.

How can I do this in Debian?

Comment: @Jesse_b : I’m just saying, whatever input file you pictured in mind when you posted your awk answer, I just asked the OP to post a snippet of it, or Atleast mention the file is /etc/group.

Comment: You probably want to make sure that only groups with a GID between [GID_MIN, GID_MAX] (from `/etc/login.defs`, usually 1000-60000) are processed: the other groups are admin, system or daemon groups and you probably don't want to mess with those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the best way to do it, but this might work:

```
awk -F: '$NF ~ "," { print $1 }' /etc/group
```

Answer (score 5):

Generally,

```
getent group | awk -F ':' '$4 ~ "," {print $1}'
```

If the 4th colon-delimited field (user list) of the group list contains a comma, then print the first colon-delimited field (group name).

Answer (score 0):

as group members are comma-delimited, only multi-member groups will have commas.
From these group-file lines, show only the line content before the first colon.

```
grep , /etc/group | cut -d: -f 1
```

Comment: What if the groups are stored in NIS or LDAP?

Comment: depends on what data is in there, the schema used, etc.

Comment: My point being that not everyone stores their group data in `/etc/group`

Comment: indeed, maybe a new question like 'how to extract group daya from system X with schema Y using tool Z' would be useful

Comment: I'm sorry again, I really wasn't clear with my first comment. I was saying that searching /etc/group is a common first step, but that group information may also be elsewhere. Using `getent` is a way to gather information from any & all repositories that are configured (including local files, LDAP, NIS, etc).

Comment: it sounds like you have a very specific problem you haven't described. Are group names ascii, utf8, utf16, or gb18030 encoded ? are they nested ? is there a single source-of-truth somewhere, maybe ldap? or perhaps something that speaks SAML ? /Maybe/ some generic command will work for you, or maybe the group-names in fact have spaces and live in some microsoft or ibm system I've never used.

Comment: I'm  not the OP!